# Does Flex save stuff to the local cache on client computer?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

My Flex app downloads a bunch of images. When the user closes the browser window (or navigates away from the page), those images shouldn't be saved in the local cache. HTTP headers for the SWF file tells browser to fetch it from the website every time -- that is, it shouldn't save the SWF file locally. I just want to make sure that any of the images that the Flex app downloads isn't saved locally.

I checked Windows XP & Flash 9 for this. And nothing was stored locally. I assume this is true across all platforms and all versions of Flash greater than 9?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that flash download contents using the underling browser so the browser caches contents for him. In my experience sometimes browsers fails to read HTTP infos for caches and uses data from cache even if the file on the server is newer. The only way that works for sure to disable caching is changing the name of the file everytime you download it.

For example you can add a random string or a timestamp to your request. image1.gif is image1.gif?nocache=1231231

Comment: Thanks! Was mainly looking for the fact the it uses the underlying browser.